# HTML5 number input element force display double zero in Firefox

Tags: html, input

The HTML5 number input element works great except when you want to display full amounts such as (desired / result)...

> 1.00//1
>
> 1.10//1.1

While I have `step="0.01"` Firefox removes the ending 00 for 1.00 in example. Even Internet Explorer displays 1.00 as desired instead of 1.

How do we force Firefox to display `1.00` like Chrome and IE without changing the input element's type attribute to any other value then `number`?

*No frameworks.*

Comment: are you open to using jquery?

Comment: Try using the "pattern" attribute.

Comment: @indubitablee No, no frameworks implies not dumping 70KB of "I didn't know the browser already natively supports JavaScript". Distilled code is *always* the best code and shows respect for not damning mobile users with poor performance. In short: competence is a required prerequisite to be considered professional.

Comment: @John I apologize for my lack of competence displayed in asking a question 3 years ago in an attempt to learn and help while I was a naive college student. I did not realize back then, and I guess I haven't gotten the memo since then, that professionalism required a sense of pompous superiority that translates to passive aggressive responses on a collaborative website (but I guess I'm learning?). But perhaps you just had a rough day in the office...Anyways, I don't believe I have the necessary skills required to help you, but good luck